# How do I print only second row into output by script in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I wrote a simple script:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c Aruba.58601 192.168.4.9 1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.3.3.1.2.1.1.11 | wc -l
```

And my output is:

```
Bad operator (INTEGER): At line 73 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf/SNMPv2-PDU
47
```

Problem is:

I need to receive only that second line (only that number) to my output, how can I do it?

Comment: indent your code, input, and output by 4 blanks to have it formatted correctly. Clarify which of the 2 lines are printing to stdout vs stderr.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to fix/replace the broken MIB file. As a quick hack you can discard SNMP tool errors like so:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c community 192.168.4.9 1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.3.3.1.2.1.1.11 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

Also take care not to post potentially sensitive SNMP community values.